# Dashboard for objects of multiple types

Tags: reporting, record-type, dashboard

I have a dashboard with few reports on the Lead object. I want to create a similar dashboard for cases. The custom fields that I'm using for the dashboard are common to both Lead and Case objects.

Is there a way to filter based on record type and have just one dashboard for all types? Or will I have to create dashboards for different record types essentially duplicating the reports and dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard comprises of dashboard components which essentially display data taking from reports. Dashboard are getting refreshed from the report data.

In a dashboard, you can display reports from multiple objects.

According, to your requirement, if you want to display dashboard components of reports of different recordtypes then you have to create separate reports (cloning of reports and change the recordtype).

We cannot able to create single dashboard which will dynamically filters based on recordtypes or other conditions on the fly.